# When printing a 0 index of an empty string, it gives an error. However, if you index the empty string from range [0:1], it prints an empty string

Tags: python-3.x

```
str = ''
print(str[0])
print(str[0:1])
```

The first print gives an error while the second prints an empty string. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Is there a character an index 0?  Did you think `str[0:1]` wouldn't be an empty string, and if so, why?

Comment: There is no character at index 0. I thought str[0:1] would produce the same error as well since it is checking the 0 index too.

Comment: Why would it "check" anything if it is an empty range/string?

Comment: I am just curious as to why python throws an error on the first case but not on the second case